# How to get the eight?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I just heard about the Farsight enclaves eight and I wanted to know if you could get them as separate figures or do If I have to modify the battlesuits in order to make them the eight?

Answer (score 1):

The only real modification you'll need is the equipment. Otherwise you just need Commander Farsight, a Riptide, a Broadside, and 5 Crisis suits. The only really "special" thing about any of them aside from Farsight is how they are equipped.

Comment: Do you happen to have a list of the equipment they use?

Comment: The equipment is listed Chapter Approved 2018, and to the best of my knowledge hasn't changed since the previous Tau codex (just some of the stats for the equipment may have). I'm also fairly certain the options you'd need DO come with the kits so unless you have really old Crisis suits it shouldn't be a problem. I'll try and check this weekend to confirm.